# Error al hacer deploy en heroku con una app de laravel

Tags: laravel, heroku

Estoy realizando una app en Laravel, me funciona perfecto en el local host pero al hacer deploy en heroku me tira este error:

```
In Compiler.php line 36:
 Please provide a valid caché Path
```

He leído y pues este error dicen sucede cuando no se encuentran los directorios:

```
Storage\
      Framework\
             Cache
             Sessions
             Testing
             View
```

En mi proyecto si se encuentran, he probado de todo, haciendo php aritsan update, install y demás sin éxito, probé borrar los directorios y volverlos a crear y nada funciona. Alguna sugerencia por favor.

Comment: probaste correr php artisan cache:clear, php artisan config:clear y php artisan view:clear?

Comment: Sí señor, también probé y persiste el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema son las rutas, que en windows son insensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero en UNIX (ubuntu por ejemplo), por lo que tus rutas deberían ir en minúscula completamente.

```
framework\
             cache
             sessions
             view
```